# How to get the node name with Graphviz and libcgraph?

Tags: c, graphviz

I'm trying to update some old code which used to work with Graphviz 2.26 and iterated over all the nodes of a graph and did something with their names:

```
for (Agnode_t *n = agfstnode(graph); n; n = agnxtnode(graph, n)) {
    ... use n->name ...
}
```

However in recent (2.30+?) versions of Graphviz, cgraph library is used for node representation and it doesn't have `name` field in its `Agnode_t` struct.

I know about `agnode()` function which allows to lookup the node by name, but there doesn't seem to be any function to go in the other direction. Am I missing something or is there really no way to access the name of the existing node with cgraph?

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks! I've somehow managed to miss it, even after staring at the man page for so long... Could you please make this the answer so that I could accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the function `agnameof`, which is listed in the "Generic Objects" section of the `cgraph` manpage:

```
char      *agnameof(void*);
```